# Getting error as required field missing

Tags: apex, xml

I am trying to insert contact from xml response but getting error as required fields missing:

XML:

```
<subscr>
    <row>
        <id>4</id>
        <subscriberid>4</subscriberid>
        <listid>1</listid>
        <first_name>NameFirst</first_name>
        <last_name>NameLast</last_name>
        <listname>NS Active</listname>
        <lid>1</lid>
        <cdate>2017-02-22 11:41:40</cdate>
        <email>test1@gmail.com</email>
        <phone/>
        <name>NameFirst NameLast</name>
        <lists>
            <id>1</id>
            <subscriberid>4</subscriberid>
            <listid>1</listid>
            <sdate>2017-02-22 11:41:48</sdate>
            <udate>0000-00-00 00:00:00</udate>
            <first_name>NameFirst</first_name>
            <last_name>NameLast</last_name>
            <listname>N Active</listname>
        </lists>
        <listslist>1</listslist>
        <fields>
            <id>2</id>
            <title>Ship to State</title>
            <descript/>
            <type>text</type>
            <isrequired>0</isrequired>
            <perstag>SHIP_TO_STATE</perstag>
            <defval/>
            <val/>
            <relid>0</relid>
        </fields>
        <fields>
            <id>10</id>
            <title>No. Orders AT</title>
            <descript/>
            <type>text</type>
            <isrequired>0</isrequired>
            <perstag>NO_ORDERS_AT</perstag>
            <defval/>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <service/>
            <ordernum>9</ordernum>
            <cdate>2017-01-24 17:06:21</cdate>
            <udate>2017-01-24 17:06:21</udate>
            <val/>
        </fields>
        <actions>
        </actions>
    </row>
</subscr>
```

Parser code:

```
List<Contact> newcontacts = new List<Contact> ();
                  Dom.Document docx = res.getBodyDocument(); 
                  dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getrootelement() ;
                  System.debug('Root Element is:' +xroot);
                  dom.XmlNode [] xrec = xroot.getchildelements(); //Get all Record Elements
                  System.debug('Child Element is:' +xrec);
                  for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec) //Loop Through Records
                  {
                      Contact c = new Contact ();

                        for (dom.XmlNode awr : child.getchildren() ) {

                           if (awr.getname() == 'id') {
                               system.debug('Id' + awr.gettext());
                               c.AC_ID__c = awr.gettext();
                            }  

                           if (awr.getname() == 'last_name') {
                               system.debug('name' + awr.gettext());
                               c.LastName = awr.gettext();
                           }  

                        }
                        newcontacts.add(c); 
                  }
                  system.debug(newcontacts);
                  insert newcontacts;
```

Debug:

```
USER_DEBUG [70]|DEBUG|(Contact:{AC_ID__c=5, LastName=t3}, Contact:{AC_ID__c=4, LastName=NameLast}, Contact:{}, Contact:{}, Contact:{})
```

Comment: You last 3 contacts don't have the `Last_Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem lies in your code at this line

```
newcontacts.add(c);
```

This is part of your outer loop, and it is going to add Contact for every node, be it ContactNode or Not. So you have build a logic around in your code to make sure that you are adding the Contact with `Last_Name` assigned, or in other words, **a valid contact**.

You should put a check like'

`if(!String.isBlank( c.Last_Name ) ) newcontacts.add(c);`

It should work.

Comment: Ok will try that I think its working..

Comment: What is the line number that error is showing?

Comment: Good. Glad to help. :)